# Wait for value before returing function result

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to make a function wait for a specific external value before returning the result?
Here is a very rudimentary example:

```
Function DoSomething() As boolean
'' ... do something external that takes time and sets a Registry value when done
'' ...

  Dim isTaskDone as Boolean 

  Do Until isTaskDone = True
     isTaskDone = Registry.GetValue("ExternalValuePath", "valName", 0)
  Loop

  Return var
End Function
```

This actually works for my needs, but I was wondering maybe there is more elegant way of achieving this?
Also I am not sure whether this solution is OK to leave it like that (using `Until` to effectively stall the function).
I apologize for a rather vague question.

Update:
I guess I am looking for some sort of simple one-call-solution, where I can call one function, it does everything I need and returns a result only when everything is done. So I know it is safe to continue.
I have also tried this with `Timers`, but I don't think it is possible to contain everything in a one-call-solution when using `Timers`.

Comment: Why do you need to wait? Is it [this `Registry.GetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) method? If so, it should not compile because it excepts three parameters.

Comment: This function is supposed to send commands to external applications and wait for them to finish and save some data to disk.
I need to use the data saved by those external applications. I need to wait, to be sure I am getting the latest version of saved data.

Comment: Sorry. I was simplifying to improve the readability of my example. Yes, that is the general method for reading the registry.

Answer (score 2):

Better approach would be to create a registry watcher using WMI. Refer the [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30624/Asynchronous-Registry-Notification-Using-Strongly), its in C# should not be a problem to convert in VB.Net

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

Your method uses a busy wait loop which will lock up your UI (and waste your CPU cycles). It's possible a `BackgroundWorker` could be used for this but you could likely also accomplish it with a `Timer`. Not very elegant perhaps but it wouldn't freeze your interface.

So rather than make it a function, a Sub would do. Then add a `Timer` with default `Interval` of 100. In your DoSomething Sub, `Enable` the timer. And your timer code would be something like this

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If Registry.GetValue("ExternalValuePath", "valName", 0) Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        'do whatever needs to be done next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The thing is, I've already tried doing this with `Timers`. And it worked. What I didn't like about `Timers` is, that the "tick" is a separate Sub from the Sub where I start the `Timer`. It's not possible to do this with Timers and contain everything in one sub/function, is it?
What I am looking for is something like one-function-solution: I call the function and it does everything I need (sends data to other system apps) and returns result only when everything is done, so I know it is safe to continue.

Comment: @EdgarsMiškins I don't believe so without causing UI or CPU issues. Even with the other answer Mukul gave. Whenever you have async communication of some sort you either have to sit there in a loop, which is not good, or do some polling (timer), which is better, or some kind of callback event, which is normally the best route. His answer would be closer to the latter.